# Downgrade Windows Enterprise to Enterprise LTSC

Tags: windows-10, licensing

It is possible to Downgrade Windows 10 Enterprise to Enterprise LTSC?

I have Windows 10 Enterprise and I want to test LTSC version

I didnt find any information on internet

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supported downgrade paths: (not surprising since LTSC is a separate distribution):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/windows-10-edition-upgrades

[image: Supported downgrade paths]